# "NzSQLException: The update count exceeded Integer.MAX_VALUE" ERROR only on JDBC connection

Tags: jdbc, netezza, nzsql

When constructing a rather large table in netezza, I get the following ERROR when using a JDBC connection:

```
org.netezza.error.NzSQLException: The update count exceeded Integer.MAX_VALUE.
```

The table **does** get created properly, but the code throws an exception.  When I try running the same SQL using `nzsql` I get:

```
INSERT 0 2395423258
```

i.e. no thrown exceptions.  It seems the variable storing the count of records in JDBC is not large enough?

Has anyone else encountered this error? How did you deal with it?

Comment: Please show the relevant code and the full exception stacktrace

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, I can show the exact code, but I am pretty sure that the *ERROR* has little to do with the actual `sql`.  I believe the issue is with the size of the constructed table.  I will try to get a full error message asap.

Comment: The error is not directly related to you query, but it is related to **how you execute it**. I don't know Netezza itself, but I am very familiar with the JDBC API. The most likely cause is using `executeUpdate`, which returns an `int` update count, which means the count must be less than or equal to 2,147,483,647 and  2395423258 is larger. Some drivers will simply overflow, others will issue a warning, but apparently Netezza throws an error.

Comment: ```create table mytable as (
    select * from verylartable
) distribute on (appropriate_key) organize on (date_field);
```

is essentially the skeleton on my `sql`.

Comment: Please show the relevant JDBC code, that shows how it is executed (and edit your question, don't use comments for relevant additions to your question).

Comment: I am using the dbeaver client and the `python` library `jaydebeapi` to connect to netezza, using in both cases the netezza provided driver.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174425/discussion-between-tipanverella-and-mark-rotteveel).

Comment: In other words, your question is incomplete and does not give us all information necessary. You need to provide all **relevant** information (including a [mcve] and full exception information) in your question. The JDBC solution would be to either use `execute(..)` or `executeLargeUpdate(..)`. I don't know how that would be possible to do with DBeaver, nor do I know anything about the jaydebeapi.

Comment: Thank you again for looking into this.  I think `executeLargeUpdate` would probably be a good remedy.  I am sorry that my question is incomplete, but I am using tools at least twice removed from the actual `JDBC` api, soit is hard for me to get detailed JAVA stacktraces of the errors.

Comment: This is the extent of the error message I get from dbeaver:

```SQL Error [1012] [HY000]: netezza.update.count.exceed.int.range
  netezza.update.count.exceed.int.range
  netezza.update.count.exceed.int.range
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify your connection string to include `ignoreUpdateCount=on` as a parameter and try again.

Comment: First of all @joeb, THANK YOU!  Also, the following connection string template seems to work well:

`jdbc:netezza://{host}:{port}/{database};ignoreUpdateCount=True`

Comment: @tipanverella I'm happy to hear that answered your question.